# What is a good structure for getting data from excel files, making calculations and writing a result in another excel file

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I have multiple excel files from which I have to take some tables as dataframes, later I have to make computations involving these dataframes and later save multiple tables in an output excel file.

Currently I have one class per excel file structure (I have multiple files with same structure but different data) where I have functions which return needed dataframes (tables).

```
class Excel1:
    def __init__(self, path1):
        self.excel1 = pd.read_excel(path1, header=[0, 1])
        
    def get_table_from_excel1(self):
        return self.excel1['something']

class Excel2:
    def __init__(self, path2):
        self.excel1 = pd.read_excel(path2, header=[0, 1])
        
    def get_table_from_excel2(self):
        return self.excel1['something_else']
```

Now I am wondering if it is a good idea to make a class result with objects of these classes as variables so that I can operate on the returned dataframes from methods and obtain results.

```
 class Result:
     def __init__(self,object_1_excel1,object_2_excel1,object_1_excel2)
        self.object_1_excel1=object_1_excel1
        self.object_1_excel1=object_2_excel1
        self.object_1_excel2=object_1_excel2
     def concat_sth_from_excel1_and_excel2(self):
        return pd.concat(self.object_1_excel1.get_table_from_excel1(),self.object_1_excel2.get_table_from_excel2()
```

Another Idea is to make one big class. Also maybe some inherentance here would be adviced? Any suggestions ?

Comment: 1) Why use class? Read these Excel files into data frames in a loop then concatenating would have achieve the same thing. 2) Why one class per file? Why not generalize the problem and design 1 class for all Excel files?

Comment: I have 2 x 2 excel files with the same structure thus I thought it would be a good idea to represent one structure with one class. I divided them in two classes to distinguish between these two structures.

Comment: I am making huge number of claculations on different tables not only concatanating, I want to have it in functions so that I can test the operations.

Comment: You can write a function that takes a data frame as input, perform the calculations and return a new data frame. If each data frame require different calculations, then write 4 functions. Not everything needs to be object-oriented